# DATE_FORMAT() in MySQL query

Tags: php, mysql, datetime, format

I'm trying to change this timestamp

> 2010-08-02 00:28:20

to month/day/year -

> 08/02/10

..in the query (I know that doing it in the query is faster).

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM posts ORDER BY post_date DESC";
```

I tried using the DATE_FORMAT() in the query many ways but I can't seem to get it right.. Can someone please share how to do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using the [manual on DATE_FORMAT()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format):

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(post_date, "%m/%d/%y");
```

Comment: Thanks, that's what I've been using but the format doesn't change.

$sql = "SELECT *, DATE_FORMAT(post_date, '%m/%d/%y') FROM posts ORDER BY post_date DESC LIMIT $start, $limit";

I get parse error with double quotes.

Comment: Mate, nvm, It works now! I was probably doing something else wrong. Thanks again! :)

Comment: @Cyber it must be `SELECT *, DATE_FORMAT(post_date, '%m/%d/%y') as date_f FROM posts ORDER BY post_date...`